# MySQL: How to find newest row using 3 keys? - not as simple as it sounds

Tags: mysql

I have a product table with 3 columns that can be used to determine the product version: major_version, minor_version and release_date.

I need a query that, as fast as possible, returns the row with the newest product version.

As I see it, the newest version can be determined like this:

a) New major release:

```
a.major_version = MAX(major_version) AND
a.major_version > any other major_version
```

b) New minor release:

```
a.major_version = MAX(major_version) AND
a.major_version = b.major_version AND
a.minor_version > b.minor_version AND
a.release_date >= b.release_date
```

c) "Silent update" of existing version:

```
a.major_version = MAX(major_version) AND
a.major_version = b.major_version AND
a.minor_version = b.minor_version AND
a.release_date > b.release_date
```

Example data:

```
CREATE TABLE mytest
(
  id                int(10)         NOT NULL,
  major_version     int(10)         NOT NULL,
  minor_version     int(10)         NOT NULL,
  release_date      datetime        NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

truncate table mytest;
insert into mytest values(1,1,1,'2012-02-26');
insert into mytest values(2,1,2,'2012-02-26');
insert into mytest values(3,1,3,'2012-02-26');
insert into mytest values(4,2,1,'2012-02-26');
insert into mytest values(5,2,2,'2012-02-26');
insert into mytest values(6,2,2,'2012-02-27');
```

My brain has deadlocked.. Can a single query accomplish this?

Comment: Can you specify the date column down to milliseconds? If so it would be easy to determine the newest release by its release date only.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do order by major_version desc, minor_version desc, release_date desc limit 1?

Comment: Your order is underspecified -- what if a.major_version = b.major version, a.minor_version > b.minor_version, but a.release_date < b.release_date? That doesn't seem to match either of conditions b or c.

Comment: @Ian: Correct, but I only use the release date as a last resort if the major and minor versions are the same. Otherwise only the version numbers should be used.

Comment: @smcg: I can't. Its a file system timestamp that doesn't contain that detail.

Comment: @Brian R: Then you should remove `AND a.release_date >= b.release_date` from condition b, and just use @menacingly's suggestion.

Comment: @menacingly: No.. Gees. Sometimes I just miss the obvious.. Gotta get more sleep. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to change the table by adding an additional column, I have an easy solution for you.

Setup the following

- Add a column called major_minor that contains the value major_version * 100 + minor_version.
- Add an index on major_minor and release date
- Now just get the max value in the back of the index

First let's make your sample data with my proposed changes

```
use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytest;
CREATE TABLE mytest 
( 
    id                int(10)         NOT NULL, 
    major_version     int(10)         NOT NULL, 
    minor_version     int(10)         NOT NULL, 
    major_minor       int(10)         DEFAULT 0,
    release_date      datetime        NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    KEY release_order_ndx (major_minor,release_date)
); 
insert into mytest (id,major_version,minor_version,release_date) values
(1,1,1,'2012-02-26'),(2,1,2,'2012-02-26'),(3,1,3,'2012-02-26'),
(4,2,1,'2012-02-26'),(5,2,2,'2012-02-26'),(6,2,2,'2012-02-27'); 
UPDATE mytest SET major_minor = major_version * 100 + minor_version;
```

Here it is loaded

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytest;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE mytest
    -> (
    ->     id                int(10)         NOT NULL,
    ->     major_version     int(10)         NOT NULL,
    ->     minor_version     int(10)         NOT NULL,
    ->     major_minor       int(10)         DEFAULT 0,
    ->     release_date      datetime        NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY(id),
    ->     KEY release_order_ndx (major_minor,release_date)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into mytest (id,major_version,minor_version,release_date) values
    -> (1,1,1,'2012-02-26'),(2,1,2,'2012-02-26'),(3,1,3,'2012-02-26'),
    -> (4,2,1,'2012-02-26'),(5,2,2,'2012-02-26'),(6,2,2,'2012-02-27');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE mytest SET major_minor = major_version * 100 + minor_version;
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 6  Changed: 6  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

Now just query the table and order by major_minor desc, release_date desc

```
mysql> select * from mytest order by major_minor desc, release_date desc;
+----+---------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | major_version | minor_version | major_minor | release_date        |
+----+---------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  6 |             2 |             2 |         202 | 2012-02-27 00:00:00 |
|  5 |             2 |             2 |         202 | 2012-02-26 00:00:00 |
|  4 |             2 |             1 |         201 | 2012-02-26 00:00:00 |
|  3 |             1 |             3 |         103 | 2012-02-26 00:00:00 |
|  2 |             1 |             2 |         102 | 2012-02-26 00:00:00 |
|  1 |             1 |             1 |         101 | 2012-02-26 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Finally, just query the table and order by major_minor desc, release_date desc limit 1

```
mysql> select * from mytest order by major_minor desc, release_date desc limit 1;
+----+---------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | major_version | minor_version | major_minor | release_date        |
+----+---------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  6 |             2 |             2 |         202 | 2012-02-27 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

If you do not want to add major_minor, then let's go with your original table

You will need to add an index on the three columns

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytest;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE mytest
    -> (
    ->     id                int(10)         NOT NULL,
    ->     major_version     int(10)         NOT NULL,
    ->     minor_version     int(10)         NOT NULL,
    ->     release_date      datetime        NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY(id),
    ->     KEY release_order_ndx (major_version,minor_version,release_date)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into mytest (id,major_version,minor_version,release_date) values
    -> (1,1,1,'2012-02-26'),(2,1,2,'2012-02-26'),(3,1,3,'2012-02-26'),
    -> (4,2,1,'2012-02-26'),(5,2,2,'2012-02-26'),(6,2,2,'2012-02-27');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Just query the table and order by major_version desc, minor_version desc, release_date desc limit 1

```
mysql> select * from mytest order by major_version desc,minor_version desc, release_date desc limit 1;
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | major_version | minor_version | release_date        |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
|  6 |             2 |             2 | 2012-02-27 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks Rolando. I have been overcomplicating things for myself it seems. I'll sleep on it, but it seems like it really is that simple.